# VSCode Freezes Kali

Tags: freeze, kali-linux, root, user, visual-studio-code

I am running Kali Linux on a Chromebook from a Live USB flash drive with persistence. (I installed it according to the instructions on their site—nothing fancy, no shenanigans.)

I recently installed VSCode, and whenever I run it as root, it works perfectly—no lag, no freezing.

However, it is apparently rather dangerous to run it as root. So, I created a normal user profile to use it under, yet whenever I run VSCode as a normal user, the laptop freezes. I cannot do **anything**, let alone access the terminal to run any diagnostics to find the problem. The entire bloody system just comes to a halt.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Doesn't vscode have any verbose output, logging, a debug mode? Nothing in syslog/dmesg afterwards? Why run Kali anyway, do other distributions experience the same freeze?